# Python.exe has stopped working while using zmq

Tags: python, pyzmq

I am running the following code and it terminates with the following message. Please refer to the screenshot.

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB) 
socket.connect('tcp://0.0.0.0:5555')
```

zmq is the Python binding for ØMQ. There are links for Python.exe stopped working, however the solutions appear to be problem specific. Please suggest the way forward. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Look like the a C module of pyzmq failed. What exactly is hard to say without any details.

Answer (score 0):

### Using ZeroMQ inside quasi-cluster-enabled clients requires more care:

Be it iPython, Jupyter or even Spyder, these python WYSIWYG- or IDE-frontends use ZeroMQ on their own internally, and quite intensively, to communicate between the GUI in "terminal" or the "notebook" and the backend python-engine(s).

So a double care is needed. Every port-mapping is even more delicate.

As one might read, O/S reports that the problems are on the backend-engine, that went mad, not on the GUI frontend.

Anyway,
rather do not use bewildered constructors like **`tcp://0.0.0.0:<port#>`** or **`tcp://*:<port#>`**

> Documentation explicitly advises another approach how to safely **`.connect()`** to localhost ( sure, that port was still free from iPython / Jupyter / Spyder own use ):

```
>>> print zmq.Socket.connect.__doc__

s.connect(addr)

        Connect to a remote 0MQ socket.

        Parameters
        ----------
        addr : str
            The address string. This has the form 'protocol://interface:port',
            for example 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'. Protocols supported are
            tcp, upd, pgm, inproc and ipc. If the address is unicode, it is
            encoded to utf-8 first.

>>>
```